# Is it possible to create a Multisig wallet with only 1 owner confirmation?

Tags: mist, wallets, multisignature

I am asking this because of I am looking for a way in case something happens to me, someone else has full authorization.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a multisig wallet with one owner's confirmation. In your case, you can add two people and set the threshold to one. So now either of you can initiate a transaction.